# Can I safely do DOM operations in a React application, but outside the React component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting ready to do my first React project, and my reading has made it pretty clear that I need to let React handle all rendering with the virtual DOM, and that I shouldn't do any manual DOM operations that would interfere with the virtual DOM calculations.

What I can't figure out, however, is this:

Suppose that I have a React component rendered in div #app in a page with other HTML. Does this mean that I have to refrain from any ordinary JavaScript DOM operations *anywhere on the page*? Or can I safely use DOM operations elsewhere on the page as long as I leave the `#app` div and elements inside the actual React component alone?

EDIT: Motivating use case

My reason for considering having non-React components manipulate the DOM outside of the React component is mostly so that the HTML can be seen by Google without jumping through a lot of hoops. Suppose that I wanted some descriptive text about the app that would be useful for SEO, and that description might have some dropdown toggles, etc. (hence the DOM issue). Would I really want/need to write everything in React just because the complex UI of the app itself uses React, if the cost is making some text hard for Google to index?

Comment: You can do DOM operations on the page but I have no idea what would happen if you modified the DOM *inside* of the React root. I'd imagine it would be quite explosive.

Comment: no. Just don't do manipulation of React-managed dom elements. And even that you technically *can* do, but you'll have to be really careful about the how, and if what you do can be done in a component's `render()`, do that instead.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your html file looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <div id="others"></div>
</body>
```

and React is initialized like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Component/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

you can safely modify `div#others` and any parts of the DOM except inside `div#app` as it is managed by React.

Answer (score 3):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but React would be a great candidate to handle *all* of your DOM "operations".

Your React components can live on the same page as elements that are manipulated with run-of-the-mill JS DOM operations, but you are introducing conflicting paradigms. If you ever think to yourself "I can't do this in React, but I know how to with jQuery", you are most likely missing something.

EDIT: Thanks for clarifying the use case. You definitely don't need to write everything in React. As others have said, I would advise you to leave the part of the DOM owned by React alone with your other JS. [Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) looks like it could be helpful for exploring SEO in React.

Comment: I've edited my question to include why I didn't necessarily want to use React for everything on the page. Perhaps now it will seem like a less silly question?

Comment: Updated my answer, sounds like a valid use case. Your question made me interested in exploring SEO in React :)