# how to integrate the Material UI slider with chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, material-ui

how to integrate the Material UI slider with chart js,
when I slide the Material UI slider, I want to move x-axis value in chart js highlighted with tooltip. I am using line chart

Answer (score -1):

When the Slider changes, it calls the function provided to the `onChange` prop:

```
handleChange = (event, value) => {
  // do something
};

render() {
  return (
    <Slider onChange={this.handleChange} />
  )
}
```

In the handleChange event, you can [update the chart data](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#adding-or-removing-data) with the new value.

You'll need to be careful that the chart is [outside the React DOM tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602481/can-i-safely-do-dom-operations-in-a-react-application-but-outside-the-react-com).

If instead you use a wrapper component for chart.js such as [react-chart-2](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2), you can pass the data to the chart using props, or a state management library such as Redux, just like any other React component.